# Using Inversify to do a Multiinject of a class with constant and injected parameters

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I have a Typescript class called insuranceController that accepts a multi inject parameter like so:

```
@injectable()
export class InsuranceController implements IInsuranceController {
    private policies: IInsurancePolicy[];

    constructor(@multiInject("IInsurancePolicy") policies: IInsurancePolicy[]) {
        this.policies = policies;
    }
}
```

The insurancePolicy class needs a number as a constructor parameter

```
@injectable()
export class InsurancePolicy implements IInsurancePolicy{
    constructor(public index: number) {
    }
}
```

So I create the bindings as follows:

```
this.container.bind<IInsurancePolicy>("IInsurancePolicy").toConstantValue(new InsurancePolicy(0));
this.container.bind<IInsurancePolicy>("IInsurancePolicy").toConstantValue(new InsurancePolicy(1));
this.container.bind<IInsurancePolicy>("IInsurancePolicy").toConstantValue(new InsurancePolicy(2));
```

This all works great. However I now want to inject a second parameter into the insurancePolicy class:

```
    constructor(public index: number,
        @inject("IIntakeLayout") intakeLayout: IIntakeLayout) {
    }
```

How can I do this? I have tried looking the techniques outlined here: [InversifyJS Injecting Literal Constructor Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439798/inversifyjs-injecting-literal-constructor-parameters), but I can't see how they would work in a multiinject scenario. Note that the InsuranceController itself is injected so I can't create it manually. How should I go about this using Inversify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper function that uses `toDynamicValue`:

```
function registerInsurancePolicy(ctr: Container, id: number) {
  ctr.bind<IInsurancePolicy>("IInsurancePolicy")
     .toDynamicValue((context) => {
        cosnt intakeLayout = context.container.get<IIntakeLayout>("IIntakeLayout");
        return new InsurancePolicy(id, intakeLayout);
     })
     .inSingletonScope();
}
```

Then use the helper:

```
registerInsurancePolicy(this.container, 1);
registerInsurancePolicy(this.container, 2);
registerInsurancePolicy(this.container, 3);
```